# MYSQLi select how to

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to select every lasted insert row with a match_id and show all match_id's on a php page, but not show multiple rows on same match_id.

Since it is a logging page for my kids football games i will insert multiple rows on same match_id to mark if he scores, so i wont be updating same match_id.

Here you can see a example how the database looks. I have some more columns also but just to get you the idea how it looks.

```html
(AI)id match_id team1 team2 result1 result2 goal timenow
1 1         US ENG   0   0 0 00:00
2 1         US ENG   1   0 0 08:00
3 1         US ENG   1   1 0 13:00
4 1         US ENG   2   1 1 20:00
5 2         US FRA   0   0 0 00:00
6 2         US FRA   1   0 1 04:00
7 2         US FRA   1   1 0 26:00
8 3         US GER   0   0 0 00:00
9 3         US GER   1   0 0 16:00
```

The result i would like to get is a php page that lists just the last row of every unique match id.

Example html/php would show lika below:

```
US-ENG 2-1
US-FRA 1-1
US-GER 1-0
```

Hope you understands what i mean :)

**EDIT:** got it working by this line of code if somebody other have the same needs.
Thanks to Akilan who lead me in right direction :)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX( id ) FROM table GROUP BY match_id) ORDER BY  `table`.`timenow` DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a order by with time and group by your match id can achieve the desired output right??

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM match_table GROUP BY match_id ORDER BY TIME(timenow)
```

Happy Coding,
AK

Comment: Hello that seems correct gives me all unique matches :) But i have tried and that only gets the first input of match_id, i have tried this.

SELECT * FROM fotboll GROUP BY match_id ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timenow) DESC 

But that dont work :(

Comment: Got it now thanks for your help, i have edited my question with the code needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
select group_concat(team1,'-',team2,' ',result1,'-',result2) from match_table group by match_id order by match_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_concat(t1.team1,'-',t1.team2,' ',t1.result1,'-',t1.result2) from table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
 ON (t1.matchid = t2.matchid AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers which describe how it overcomes the OP issue.